# C Strange stack-overflow when calling another function

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I work with VS2012, on a project which combines C and C++ code. This problem does not happen when running the code in GCC.

(See screenshot at the bottom)

The below C function fails on stack overflow, **immediately** when the function `FeedForwardNetwork_new_from_string()` is called. The debugger breaks after the call to that function, but before any of that function's code is being executed.

```
FeedForwardNetwork *FeedForwardNetwork_new_from_file(const char *filePath) {
    char *file_contents;
    long input_file_size;
    FILE *input_file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
    FeedForwardNetwork *ffn;

    if (input_file == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
    input_file_size = ftell(input_file);
    rewind(input_file);
    file_contents = (char*)malloc((input_file_size + 1) * (sizeof(char)));
    fread(file_contents, sizeof(char), input_file_size, input_file);
    file_contents[input_file_size] = '\0';
    fclose(input_file);

    ffn = FeedForwardNetwork_new_from_string(file_contents);

    free(file_contents);

    return ffn;
}
```

This is the flow to the function, starting from `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    VideoAnalyzerUtils::getNeuralNetwork();

    return 0;        
}
```

The function `getNeuralNetwork()`, which calls the problematic function:

```
FeedForwardNetwork *VideoAnalyzerUtils::getNeuralNetwork() {
    if (VideoAnalyzerUtils::network_ == NULL) {
        VideoAnalyzerUtils::network_ = FeedForwardNetwork_new_from_file("net.txt");
    }
    return VideoAnalyzerUtils::network_;
```

}

The implementation of `FeedForwardNetworkSettings_new_from_string()`:

```
FeedForwardNetworkSettings *FeedForwardNetworkSettings_new_from_string(const char *settingsStr) {
    char buffer[NEURON_STR_READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int withBias;
    double trainingRate ;
    double outputLayerTrainingRate;
    int hiddenLayerType;
    int outputLayerType;
    FeedForwardNetworkSettings *settings;

    _Neuron_getValueFromString(settingsStr, "withBias=", buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "") == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    withBias = atoi(buffer);
    _Neuron_getValueFromString(settingsStr, "trainingRate=", buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "") == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    trainingRate = atof(buffer);
    _Neuron_getValueFromString(settingsStr, "outputLayerTrainingRate=", buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "") == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    outputLayerTrainingRate = atof(buffer);
    _Neuron_getValueFromString(settingsStr, "hiddenLayerType=", buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "") == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    hiddenLayerType = atoi(buffer);
    _Neuron_getValueFromString(settingsStr, "outputLayerType=", buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "") == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    outputLayerType = atoi(buffer);


    settings = (FeedForwardNetworkSettings*)malloc(sizeof(FeedForwardNetworkSettings));
    settings->withBias_ = withBias;
    settings->trainingRate_ = trainingRate;
    settings->outputLayerTrainingRate_ = outputLayerTrainingRate;
    settings->hiddenLayerType_ = (NeuronActivationFunction)hiddenLayerType;
    settings->outputLayerType_ = (NeuronActivationFunction)outputLayerType;

    return settings;
}
```

Can you please help me to understand why it would happen and how to fix it?

A screenshot of the error (Please use browser's zoom-in to see it better):

[Screenshot http://s23.postimg.org/fvtetkjgq/c_error.jpg](http://s23.postimg.org/fvtetkjgq/c_error.jpg)

Comment: You're probably blowing your stack - only way to guess would be to see the called function's code, not the caller's.

Comment: Do not post images. Post text!

Comment: Do you have a large local array somewhere else? Is it possible to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: I added the whole flow starting from `main()` and until the function. It is very short...

Comment: I don't have any local array

Comment: Show the `FeedForwardNetwork_new_from_string` function

Comment: There are a few things with the code you show that are suspect. The first is that you open a file in binary mode, the you terminate the data you read as a string and call a function that contains the word `string` in it's name, indicating it works on strings/text. Is the data binary or textual? Secondly, you don't seem to have any error handling. What if the memory allocation fails? Or if the `fopen` call fails? (The last is not unusual when running in an IDE because the programs working directory might not be what you expect).

Comment: NEWS - Checked now - the function `FeedForwardNetwork_new_from_string()` crashes anyway on same issue, even when I call it from main directly. Will now add its implementation

Comment: Now the big question, what is `NEURON_STR_READ_BUFFER_SIZE` and what is it defined to?

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't use symbol names with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter, those names are reserved for the implementation (compiler/standard library) in all scopes. Also, if you are really programming in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (or other functions returning `void *`).

Comment: baaaaaaa... It's `#define NEURON_STR_READ_BUFFER_SIZE 1048576` !!

Comment: Now everything gets clear. I'll change it to malloc

Comment: @SomethingSomething you write _I don't have any local array_. Yes you do in the `*FeedForwardNetworkSettings_new_from_string` function: `char buffer[NEURON_STR_READ_BUFFER_SIZE];` : this is a local array and `[NEURON_STR_READ_BUFFER_SIZE` is probably very large.

Answer (score 1):

You hit the 1 Mb default stack size of the Visual Studio compiler. `gcc` has 8 Mb default stack which is why it works with `gcc`.

You can either allocate the buffer dynamically, using `malloc`or `calloc`, or increase the stack size.

Visual Studio accepts the following flags to set the stack size:

`/STACK:reserve[,commit]`

or

`/F stack-size-in-bytes`